# 'pod install' isn't adding the framework to my Xcode project

Tags: xcode, swift, git, cocoapods

I would like to build and run this project.

https://github.com/JakeLin/SwiftWeather

I 'git clone' then 'cd' to its directory, then run 'pod install', which installs all the pod without an error.

In the folder of my project I can see the pod and it also appears when I open the .xcworkspace. However when I just open my .xcodeproject it throws me an error at the 'import ...' statement, where I try to import the pod.

How can I fix this?

PS: When I open my .xcworkspace I can see and open everything within the Pods project, but I can only see the actual project but not open it.

Thank you very much. :-)

Comment: This is to be expected - you should be opening (and working in) the workspace after installing your pods, you should no longer open your `.xcodeproj` file. I think the `pod install` command even mentions this after executing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use .xcworkspace instead of .xcodeproject. You need workspace to support cocoa pod.

Answer (score 0):

> please go through [Cocoapods install](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html) it may helpful for you